# Cannot abort the Restore DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, smo

I would like to provide the user with the Cancel button - to abort a restore in progress. To do this, in the  `Restore.PercentComplete` event handler I check if the user have clicked the Cancel button and call the `Restore.Abort()`. But this does not help:

The SMO throws exception:

Restore failed for Server 'MICHAEL7'.
 
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
 
Stack Trace:   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)

The DB stays in the "Restoring" mode forever. Here is the relevant code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

private volatile bool _CancelRestore = false;
private Restore _RestoreDB;
private Server _myServer;
private Database _currentDatabase;

// user hits Cancel buttton
public void CancelRestore()
{
    _CancelRestore = true;
}

// Restore.PercentComplete event handler
private static void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs args) 
{
    if (_CancelRestore)
    {
        _RestoreDB.Abort();

          // Disable the kills to let some time to Abort()

        // Stop all processes running on the _currentDatabase database
        // _myServer.KillAllProcesses(_currentDatabase.Name);

        // Stop the _currentDatabase database
        // NOTE: it is a temp name DB: I do not restore over my application DB!
        // _myServer.KillDatabase(_currentDatabase.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", args.Percent);
    }
}
```

The Backup/Restore functionality was implemented with the help of this article: [SQL Server 2005 Database Backup and Restore using C# and .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26390/SQL-Server-2005-Database-Backup-and-Restore-using)

Thanks.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see if `CompletionStatusInPercent` is hit often (it should be), also add a `volatile` keyword to `_CancelRestore` this should disable any CPU cache for the bool and force threads to check the actual value of a bool (although this is not guaranteed).

Comment: hi @oleksii. Thanks for the volatile. The breakpoint is there and is visited alright. The problem I guess is in the SMO somewhere. I need a working example of backup/restore abort.

Comment: Comment out the Kill stuff! You aren't giving it time to put itself back together!

Comment: hi @Tony, kill stuff out - Done. Still the same exception.

Comment: If you do it manually as in cancel a restore what happens? Can't say I've done it myself, this sort of thing makes me nervous, more likely to let it finish and then restore the previous backup to undo the "incorrect" restore.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was stuck with the same problem and I found a solution that works for me.

Instead of KillDatabase I use the following:

```
sqlRestore.Abort();
sqlRestore.Wait(); //This will wait until the restore operation is canceled
Database db = _server.Database(databaseName);
if (db != null)
    db.Drop(); // This will drop the "half" restored Database
```

Should say, that I'm using SqlRestoreAsync.

KillDatabase() will kill all connections, so KillAllProcesses() is obsolete here.

Her is my full code:

```
public async Task<bool> Restore(string backupFile, string databaseName, IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Restore sqlRestore = null;

    bool result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(backupFile, DeviceType.File);
            sqlRestore = new Restore
            {
                Action = RestoreActionType.Database,
                Database = databaseName,
                Partial = false,
                ReplaceDatabase = true,
                PercentCompleteNotification = 1
            };
            sqlRestore.PercentComplete += (s, e) => progress.Report(e.Percent);
            sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);

            if (_server.Databases[databaseName] != null)
                _server.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);

            sqlRestore.SqlRestoreAsync(_server);

            while (sqlRestore.AsyncStatus.ExecutionStatus == ExecutionStatus.InProgress)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            if (sqlRestore.AsyncStatus.ExecutionStatus == ExecutionStatus.Succeeded)
            {
                Database db = _server.Databases[databaseName];
                if (db != null)
                    db.SetOnline();

                _server.Refresh();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            sqlRestore.Abort();
            sqlRestore.Wait();
            Database db = _server.Databases[databaseName];
            if (db != null)
                db.Drop();
            return true;
        }
        catch (ConnectionFailureException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _server.KillDatabase(databaseName);
            return false;
        }
    }, ct);
    return result;
}
```